# SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:281

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've been searching for this but it always gives me irrelevant answers hope you guys takes time to save me from this one. thank you for your future answers.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:281

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-form',
  templateUrl: 'form.html',
})
export class FormPage {
  data: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
    let localData = this.http.get('assets/data/menus.json').map(res => res.json().items);
    localData.subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

  toggleSection(i) {
    this.data[i].open = !this.data[i].open;
  }

  toggleItem(i, j) {
    this.data[i].children[j].open = !this.data[i].children[j].open;

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FormPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the JSON that are you trying to parse ?

Comment: yes i have menus.json

Comment: here   assets/data/menus.json

Comment: {
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Traditional",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Pizza Samali",
              "information": "pitsa sa albertos bahug taler",
              "price":
            },
            {
              "name": "Pizza Samali",
              "information": "pitsa sa albertos bahug taler",
              "price":
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have malformed your JSON. Te **price** must have a value, even if is a empty string.
Try it like this.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Traditional",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Pizza Samali",
              "information": "pitsa sa albertos bahug taler",
              "price": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "Pizza Samali",
              "information": "pitsa sa albertos bahug taler",
              "price": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```